# Django custom authentication doesn't redirect as expected

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

from Signin When i redirect to Logged_IN to get request.user it gives me error **'User' object is not iterable**.i think login request is not passed to Logged_IN.

But it works well with in Signin View.It responses request.user.

In Index it request.user.is_authenticated() is always true even when i dont signed in.
Also I have created custom user instead of using default user.


Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from signup.forms import AuthenticationForm, RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login , logout

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect,Http404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

#@login_required
def Index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse("Welcome")
    else:
        return render(request,'signup/index.html',{'form':AuthenticationForm,})

def Signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    #return HttpResponse(request.user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signup:logged_in',args=()))
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

def Signup(request):
    return render(request,'signup/signup.html',{'form': RegistrationForm,})


def Logged_IN(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse(request.user)
        #return render(request,'signup/user.html',{})
```

Here is my backends.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
#from django.contrib.auth.models import  check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import User

class UserAuthBackend(object):
    """
    A custom authentication backend. Allows users to log in using their username.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """
        Authentication method
        """
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Here is my Custom user models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.username)
    username=models.CharField("UserName",max_length=100,unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        pass

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        pass
```

Comment: Why are you returning `HttpResponse(request.user)`?  What effect do you expect this to have?

Comment: just want to know whether user is logged in or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) expects a string, or an iterable. You are getting the error because you have passed the `user` instance.

```
return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

Django tries to iterate over `request.user` and you get the error because model instances are not iterable.

You could change the view to return the username instead.

```
return HttpResponse(request.user.username)
```